# Vim cmdline breaks my view of a file when outputting errors from linters

Tags: vimrc, error

I really don't know how to explain this, but when I get an error in the cmdline with some linters (Ale and Syntastic for example), it shifts up and basically breaks the view of my code.

Vim itself doesn't shift along with it. Almost like the new lines that are a result of error expanding up write empty lines over the lines of the file. It doesn't edit the file, but the view doesn't update and I have to go over the file with cursor to force a rerender.

I have attached a [video to explain](https://streamable.com/s8oy5).

Also here is my [.vimrc file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rtaibah/.dotfiles/master/.vimrc)

Comment: The solution depends on how the linters are run and how you might be able to redirect those errors. You should be able to refresh the screen by typing Ctrl-L.